# 先祖の要素に特定のクラスを持たない要素のCSSセレクタについて

Tags: css

先祖（つまり階層を遡ったすべての親）が特定のクラスを持たない要素をセレクタしたいと考えています。

:not(クラス) セレクタを利用すれば実現できそうですが、直接の親子でないと機能しませんでした

例えば
.oya というクラスを持たない .ko と .mago にスタイルを適用させたい場合...
(chrome)

:not(.oya)>.ko {...} ...効く
:not(.oya)>.ko>.mago {...} ...効かない

:not(.oya) .ko {...} ...効かない
:not(.oya) .mago {...} ...効かない

:not()セレクタに、直下ではなく配下を指定することはできないのでしょうか？
仕様や他の実現方法について、アドバイスをよろしくお願いします。
（jQueryなどでは比較的簡単なんですが...）

```css
:not(.oya-a)>.ko-a {
  color: #ff0000;
}

:not(.oya-a)>.ko-a>.mago-a {
  color: #00ff00;
}

:not(.oya-b) .ko-b {
  color: #ff0000;
}

:not(.oya-b) .mago-a {
  color: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="oya-a">
    親A
    <div class="ko-a">
      子A
      <div class="mago-a">孫A</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ko-a">
    子A
    <div class="mago-a">孫A</div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="oya-b">
    親B
    <div class="ko-b">
      子B
      <div class="mago-b">孫B</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ko-b">
    子B
    <div class="mago-b">孫B</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

やりたいことを整理するとこういうことですね？

```css
div{padding-left: 1em}
:not(.oya-a)>.ko-a{
  color:#ff0000;
}
:not(.oya-a)>.ko-a>.mago-a{
  color:#00ff00;
}

:not(.oya-b) .ko-b{
  color:#ff0000;
}
:not(.oya-b) .mago-b{
  color:#00ff00;
}
```

```html
※括弧内が期待する結果
<div class="oya-a">
  親A
  <div class="ko-a">
    子A（色が付かない）
    <div class="mago-a">孫A</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ko-a">
  子A（色が付く）
  <div class="mago-a">孫A</div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="oya-b">
  親B
  <div class="ko-b">
    子B（色が付かない）
    <div class="mago-b">孫B</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ko-b">
  子B（色が付く）
  <div class="mago-b">孫B</div>
</div>
```

`:not(.oya-b)` は `*:not(.oya-b)` と等価で、クラスがoya-bでない要素すべてにマッチします。`console.log(document.querySelectorAll(':not(.oya-b)')` などとしてみるとわかりやすいですが、bodyをはじめとしたほとんどのタグがこれに該当します。その子孫にある `.ko-b` ということですから、bodyなどの子孫にある `.ko-b` が該当します。

「先祖に`.oya-b`を持たない`.ko-b`」ではなく、「`.oya-b`以外を先祖に持つ`.ko-b`」です。

子セレクタの場合も「親に`.oya-a`を持たない`.ko-a`」ではなく「`.oya-a`以外を親に持つ`.ko-a`」ですが、これは同じ意味なので、あなたの期待通りに動いているというだけです。

jQueryでは `:not()` の中に `xx yy` といった複合セレクタを書くことができますが、CSS3の `:not()` には単純なセレクタしか書くことができません。[CSS4では `:not()` が強化されるようですが](http://myakura.github.io/n/selectors4.html#not-and-selector-list)、それでも結合子は使えないようです。